# Android ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2

Tags: android, arrays, loops, for-loop

the list:`private List<EventRect> mEventRects;`
this list contains the records `event.getIdOperatore() == 1` and `event.getIdOperatore() == 3`
I get this error:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
```

code:

```
int [] o = {1,3};
private void drawEvents(float startFromPixel, Canvas canvas) {
    if (mEventRects != null && mEventRects.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mEventRects.size(); i++) {
            if(mEventRects.get(i).event.getIdOperatore() == o[i]){
                Log.d("mEventRects",
                mEventRects.get(i).event.getIdOperatore() + 
                " idOperatore " + o[i]);
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `mEventRects.size() != o.length`.

If you are sure they are equal then try it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<mEventRects.size() && i<o.length; < i++) {
```

Comment: I'm sure, are the same, but it seems to read only the first record, that is only **mEventRects﹕ 1 idOperatore 1**

Answer (score 0):

Your int array `int[] o` has only two elements. So in your `for()` loop, if your iterator goes any higher than 1, you will get the exception. So for this code to work, your `mEventRects.size()` needs to be 2 or lower.

Instead of storing your 1 and 3 inside an int array, just test for them explicitly in the `for()` loop. So instead of this:

```
if(mEventRects.get(i).event.getIdOperatore() == o[i])
```

You'll want to do this:

```
if(mEventRects.get(i).event.getIdOperatore() == 1)
```

or...

```
if(mEventRects.get(i).event.getIdOperatore() == 3)
```